# PHP finding "words" within a string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to compare 2 lists of strings against each other and output strings which contain the strings searched for. should be very easy, i just can't figure it out.

to overly simplify it, let's use arrays. I am accessing an API with SOAP and running it against my own list contained in a table, but.... let's use arrays. the comparison is what i'm having trouble with.

hit submit button on listsearch.php and it executes.

```
ARRAY Mylist : TED, DEAD, FIRST, LAST, PUPPY

ARRAY TheirList..<br> teddybearnoose, <br>hauntedhouse, <br>hehasdeparted, <br>deadmouse, <br>walkingdead, <br>thegratefuldead, <br>firstkiss, <br>thinkfirst,<br> firsttobelast,<br> firstmanonthemoon, <br>firstreattempted, <br>somecrap, <br>something, <br>notdisplayed, <br>50000otherwords,<br> miscjunk
```

outputs as:

```
TEDdybearnoose<br>
haunTEDhouse<br>
hehasdeparTED<br>
DEADmouse<br>
walkingDEAD<br>
thegratefulDEAD<br>
FIRSTkiss<br>
thinkFIRST<br>
FIRSTtobeLAST <--- note<br>
FIRSTmanonthemoon<br>
FIRSTreattempTED <--- note<br>
<br>
```

only outputs strings which contain a string in my list, in any position.  CAPS is just to make the words stand out to you. not important.

now, part 2?

same "TheirList", except i type a keyword into a text area, and select whether i want it at the beginning end or anywhere from a dropdown.

keywordsearch.php

search for: [ TED ] at: [beginning / end / anywhere] of string.

how would you make that one work?

Thanks in advance.   This should be a breeze for most of you. I appreciate it. i'll try to answer questions promptly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos()` to find the position of a substring ([docs](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strpos.php)).

It makes it very easy to check whether the substring occurred at the beginning or at the end of the string:

```
// String contains substring
strpos($string, $substring) !== false;

// String starts with substring
strpos($string, $substring) === 0;

// String ends with substring
strpos($string, $substring) === strlen($string) - strlen($substring);
```